# Pinterest API - Authorization failed

Tags: oauth-2.0, pinterest

I created an new Pinterest API and used PostMan to get an Access Token. I have not tried to get it approved. When I try to use an API called PinSharp, the pinterest client fails to get the boards and just the an exception message "Authorization failed".

Does anyone know how to get passed this so the app can be used to pin images?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your app approved by Pinterest prior to being able to pull data from the API.  After you complete the application process and are approved, you will see a "Visit API docs" link on your app page that will then provide detailed information on how to access the API.

I'm not sure if there are multiple documentation locations depending on the type of access you are given, but the documentation I have access to is: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/pinner_app